# Dropbox Authentication from Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, dropbox-api

I did research for this one a lot, but could not find anything that could help me. 
So I am working on a chrome extension and integrating drop box with it. What I am trying to achieve is authentication on click of the extension icon.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
var init = function () { 
var client = new Dropbox.Client({
key: 'mykey'
});
client.authDriver(new Dropbox.AuthDriver.ChromeExtension({
receiverPath: '/views/chrome_oauth_receiver.html'
}));
if (client.isAuthenticated()) {
client.getAccountInfo(function (error, accountInfo) {
if (error) {
console.log(error);
return;
}
console.log(accountInfo.name);
});
} 
else {
client.authenticate(function (error, client) {
if (error) {
console.log(error);
return;
}
console.log(client);
});
}
}
```

So what ends up happening is this- on every click of the extension icon, it gets redirected to the authentication page where user-permission is sought, and this happens in a new tab outside the extension. My extension window ( or popup ) is already closed by now.

Ideally I want this to happen the first time around. From the next time ( unless the user opts out) the code - client.isAuthrenticated() should return true. But it returns false every time around. 
We do need to create a new instance of client every time around, right ?

If I use interactive:false in the authenticate call, redirection to permissions page does not happen, but client.isAuthenticated() is still false.
What is the basis of the return vaue of client.isAuthenticated() - must be something in localStorage.

Comment: There are some instructions for using Dropbox.AuthDriver.ChromeExtension here: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/stable/guides/builtin_drivers.md#dropboxauthdriverchromeextension Have you followed those?

Comment: This is being tracked here https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/issues/203#issuecomment-65354351